# Launching an SSRS report from asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, reportingservices-2005

I have an asp.net web app and I need to launch a pdf report that is developed in SSRS using SQL 2005. The SSRS report query has been created. How can I go about launching the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the ReportViewer control? You can use the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839%28VS.80%29.aspx) method to render the report to the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

The "ReportViewer" webpart might be able to do what you want: [How to: Add the Report Viewer Web Part to a Web Page (SharePoint Integrated Mode)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326362%28SQL.90%29.aspx).